# PHP array of SQL statements

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to refactor a switch statement to a collection. The switch statement selects the correct SQL query to run based on the switch conditional.

The queries all have concatenations within the switch statement, which does not work in an array within a class. Here is an example query similar to what I am dealing with:

```
"select qqqq,wwww,eeee,rrrr,tttt, 'yyyy' as uuuu from " . CONSTANT . ".aaaa as ssss inner join ' . CONSTANT2 . '.ddddd .... etc.
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Here is something close to the actual code. I made some changes for privacy:

```
 <?php
```

namespace Collections;

class ScheduleSQL {

```
private $sql;

public function __construct($plant)
{

    $sql = [
    'fgfghh' => "select fdgsgdfg, sgfdfgfg, rotary_priority,sfgfgfddg,sgfsgf, JB_ULT_CUST,jbr_status, jb_cust_want_date, routing_done, jb_date_need, js_time_ship, js_ship_via, jb_job_desc, rot.job_nbr, rot.job_plt, rot.job_type, sdfgdfgdf, js_ship_to, js_shipto_name, js_state, js_city, jbr_created as cvbvbv,xbvbvb, xbvbvb,xvbvbbcvb, vbvbvbas job_class, ruling_completed,scheduled_rule_date, converter, scenario_id, scenario_subdomain, transfer_type,transfer_job, jb_slope, jb_inch
                    from ' . DB_RASTER_LIB . 'jbraster as rot
                    inner join  ' . DB_STR_LIB . '.sessions_and_jobs as str
                        on rot.job_type = str.job_type and str.jb_job = rot.job_nbr and cgc.jb_plt = rot.job_plt
                    inner join ' . DB_RASTER_LIB . '.rot_job_sp as rot_sp
                        on rot_sp.jb_job = str.jb_job and rot_sp.jb_plt = str.jb_plt and rot_sp.job_type = rot.job_type
                    left outer join ' . DB_RASTER_LIB . '.job_data as rot_jd
                        on rot_jd.job_nbr = str.jb_job and rot_jd.job_plt = str.jb_plt and rot_jd.job_type = rot.job_type
                    inner join ' . DB_STR_LIB . '.jobshp as shp
                        on str.jb_job = shp.js_job and str.jb_plt = shp.js_plt and shp.job_type = rot.job_type and shp.js_primary = 1
                    where rot.job_plt = $plant and rot.job_type <> A and (jbr_status is null or jbr_status<>99)
                    order by jb_date_need asc"
];  
} 

public function getSQL($type)
{
    return $this->sql[$type];
}
```

}

Comment: So CONSTANT and CONSTANT2 are the things that vary within the switch statement? Is it a custom Collection class that you want to use?

Comment: @TZANΑθηνά correct on both points

Comment: Please show us what the custom Collection looks like. I was originally thinking of a simple associative array

Comment: And what about a function to generate the SQL?

Comment: Please show the actual code. Concatenations should work when assigning to an array.

Comment: I added some code as an edit. All I changed is some of the SQL cols and PHP constants to random characters.

Comment: Could those who down voted my question post an explanation as to why? I am trying to learn and be a good citizen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was in how the variable $plant is pulled into the query string.

Including it within the double-quotes worked outside of the array - in the original context of a switch statement. However, when pulled into an array as I am doing, the variable has to be outside of the double-quotes.

i.e.

```
"query statement parts".$string."other query string parts"
```

Thanks to all who responded.